# How to stay mathematically sharp during a engineering gap year

Tags: advice

I am on a gap year due to financial reasons but my question is how to stay active during the gap year. I fear that I would lose all the momentum and fail my first year. I will be studying engineering at a top british university(Either of Oxbridge). Is it wise to cover the first year or just a waste of time since I'd forget most of it?

Comment: One idea could be to try and frequent this site and read questions, answers and participate.

Comment: Participate here. I'm kinda going through a gap year as well, and I found that my participation here kept me reasonably sharp.

Comment: This site and other maths site can help you engage yourself in activities it's fun and you won't be lazy. I myself using this as right now I have nothing to do and nowhere to go and believe me I have learned many stuffs from here with 10-12 days. So try to participate as much as you can on here.

Comment: Also there is a site called brilliant which takes quizes on maths.

Comment: Find an interesting math book to read and study. Springer's *Readings in mathematics* series would be a good place to start. If you have not yet studied analysis, I'd also suggest the book *Understanding Analysis* by Abbott, which is a lively and stimulating read with fun exercices.

Comment: Also most of the questions here doesn't make sense at all(too complex most of the time).